# How do I get an environment variable available in my docker file into my React component

Tags: reactjs, docker, jenkins

Can anyone please tell me how to pick an environment variable from my docker file running in Jenkins pipeline into my React component?

Comment: This could be helpful for using the variables server side and transferring them to the client: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51055817/in-react-how-do-i-pass-backend-rest-apis-to-my-frontend/51055853#51055853

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webpack, you can use [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) to get an environment variable at compile time from Jenkins, and then define it as a global constant for your React components to use.

Or, you can just use `fs.readFileSync` to read and parse your docker file in your webpack.config.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `process.env.{{your_env}}` to access the environment variable within your react application.

Noramally, when you are setting environment variables with `ENV` command in your Dockerfile, those will be set as system level environment variables within the container. You can make sure whether they are correctly set to container by issuing a `export` command within a bash prompt. If your variables are included in the result of the `export` command, then you can easily access these variables with `process.env` inside of your react app.

Answer (score 0):

Use them in your code like variables with `process.env.VAR_NAME`.

If you are using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) make sure your environment variables begin with `REACT_APP_` for them to be loaded.

So if you need `KEY=123` it should be defined as `REACT_APP_KEY=123` and get it in your code with `const key = process.env.KEY; // returns 123`